How to display folder structure and files in the Front End using Next JS
I am trying to show all the subfolders and files in the "data" folder of my project as dropdown elements in the Front End of one of my page.tsx files in my Next JS application, but I can't find a way to do this without hardcoding the directories...
Is there a simple way to do this?
I tried using useState, getStaticProps, etc. but always end up with errors in the compilation process...
